# generating JAXB objects from XML

Tags: jaxb, xsd

I have a problem, I have an XSD file which I am trying to validate with an XML:

The XSD starts with:

```
<xs:schema id="Notes"
targetNamespace="http://mynotes.com/Notes"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://mynotes.com/Notes"
xmlns:mstns="http://mynotes.com/Notes"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Then I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="noNamespaceSchemaLocation" xmlns="http://mynotes.com/Notes">
```

In that case I can validate, but when I use JAXB to create an objects, the objects don't get populated and all their members are null.

But, If I modify the XML to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notes>...
```

In this case the JAXB objects are created successfully, but the validation fails...

I guess I am missing something with the namespace declaration, your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the default namespace qualification for your JAXB model.  Below is an example, you will need to adjust the package to be the same as your domain classes.

**com/example/package-info.java**

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://mynotes.com/Notes",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html